# What is the "double" mentioned in Isaiah 40:2?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 40:1-2 (KJV)

> 1 Comfort ye, comfort ye my people, saith your God.   2 Speak ye comfortably to Jerusalem, and cry unto her, that her warfare is accomplished, that her iniquity is pardoned:  for she hath received of the LORD's hand ***double*** for all her sins.

The tone in this chapter seems to be consolatory but the double is not clear to which it refers to.

There seems to be some ambiguity in the above text

Does this refer to double chastisement for sins committed or double recompense after iniquity had been pardoned?

Comment: “Double” could simply be synonymous with “an eye for an eye”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Double Chastisement (Payment/Recompense) for Jerusalem's Sins

The prophetic cry of Isa 40:1-2 follows Isaiah's declaration to Hezekiah about the coming judgment from Babylon in Isa 39:5-7 (NKJV):

> 5 Then Isaiah said to Hezekiah, “Hear the word of the LORD of hosts: 6 ‘Behold, the days are coming when all that is in your house, and what your fathers have accumulated until this day, shall be carried to Babylon; nothing shall be left,’ says the LORD. 7 ‘And they shall take away some of your sons who will descend from you, whom you will beget; and they shall be eunuchs in the palace of the king of Babylon.’”

While this prophetic judgment was in response to Hezekiah's opening the palace for Babylonian inspection (39:1-4), Hezekiah is (smugly?) pleased that it is not coming in his days (39:8).

But following the prophecy of judgment by Babylon and Hezekiah's reaction, Isaiah at some point (it may not have been immediately then) also gave this prophecy of comfort in chapter 40, which also declares the extent of *Jerusalem*'s payment to be "double for all her sins."

Fast-forward to Jeremiah's day, when things are rapidly approaching this fulfillment of Babylon's conquest. Jeremiah gives a specific prophecy about a time frame in Jer 25:11-12

> 11 And this whole land shall be a desolation and an astonishment, and these nations shall serve the king of Babylon seventy years.
> 12 ‘Then it will come to pass, when seventy years are completed, that I will punish the king of Babylon and that nation, the land of the Chaldeans, for their iniquity,’ says the LORD; ‘and I will make it a perpetual desolation

The key here is the **seventy years** the "land shall be a desolation."<sup>`1`</sup> The beginning of this comes to pass in Jeremiah's day with Babylon's destruction of Jerusalem in 586 B.C., but as learned in the book of Haggai, the land does not start producing again until the completion of the Temple has been done (Hag 2:15-19), which is in 516 B.C. (70 years).

But though the Temple is done, *Jerusalem itself* is still uninhabited until the rebuilding of the walls by Nehemiah, which is ***another 70 years later***, in 445 B.C., and so ***double*** the amount of time that the rest of the land of Israel.

Isaiah's prophecy was thus of Jerusalem having to lay desolate for twice the time of the rest of the land for her sins, but in his prophecy, that payment time is past (hence the comfort), and so Israel is to be looking then for the one noted in Isa 40:3, the coming of the one preceding the coming of the LORD himself:

> The voice of one crying in the wilderness: “Prepare the way of the LORD; Make straight in the desert A highway for our God.

Iniquity is pardoned, their God is coming—take comfort.

[P.S. I have more I want to add in details above, but no time now, so I'll have to come back to it.]

---

<sup>`1`</sup> The 70 years of the land is a different period from the 70 years of service to the king of Babylon. The land's *desolation*, as discussed above, is from 586 B.C. (destruction of Jerusalem) to 516 B.C. (completion of 2nd Temple), while the *service* is from 605 B.C. (the 1st deportation to Babylon) to 535 B.C. (the return by Zerubbabel and the laying of the 2nd Temple's foundation).

Answer (score 3):

The meaning is double chastisement, not double recompense. This matches the imagery of Isaiah 51:17, which describes Jerusalem as having drunk a cup of wrath *from God's hand* (as in this verse).

If recompense for punishment were meant, it wouldn't have been described as "for all her sins"; obviously, recompense isn't for sins, but for the punishments, and punishments are not mentioned. Contrast Joel 2:25, which promises recompense for years of famine, not for sins.

The translation "for all her sins" comes from the words בְּכָל חַטֹּאתֶיהָ. The preposition "for" (-בְּ) is used elsewhere in connection with sins in a number of places in the Bible with the meaning of punishment: אִישׁ בְּחֶטְאוֹ יוּמָתוּ, "each man will die *for* his sin" (Deuteronomy 24:16); בַּעֲו‍ֹן בִּצְעוֹ קָצַפְתִּי וְאַכֵּהוּ "*for* his sin I was angry and struck him" (Isaiah 57:17); בַּעֲוֺנוֹ יָמוּת, "*for* his sin he will die" (three times nearly identically in Ezekiel 3:18-20). The meaning is thus likely to be the same here.

What is stressed in these verses is the idea of comfort, but not of recompense.

Answer (score 1):

In the portuguese version BPT Edição Comum the passage is clearer for me

> Falem ao coração de Jerusalém e proclamem que acabaram os seus
> trabalhos forçados e está pago o seu crime; que já recebeu do Senhor o
> dobro do castigo pelos seus pecados.

which translates to something within these lines

> Speak to the heart of Jerusalem and proclaim that your forced labor is
> over and your crime is paid for; who has already received twice the
> punishment from the Lord for his sins.

It reads that the forced works ended because the Lord received double as much work than originally expected. So we'd be speaking of your first case - **double chastisement for sins committed**.

The word used here for "double" is [Strong's H3718 - kephel](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H3718&t=KJV) and can be seen here, in Job 11:6 (KJV)

> And that he would shew thee the secrets of wisdom, that they are
> **double** to that which is! Know therefore that God exacteth of thee less than thine iniquity deserveth.

and Job 41:13 (KJV)

> Who can discover the face of his garment? or who can come to him with
> his **double** bridle?

Whether this double means really "double" I have my doubts since the passage seems to indicate "more than necessary".

Comment: Very Good answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I heard a very interesting explanation for this apparent reference to 'double chastisement.'In ancient Israel, it was incumbent on debtors to write the full amount of their debt on a piece of parchment, (eg), and attach it to an outside part of their dwelling, in full view of whoever passed by. If a person of standing, seeing it, were to decide, as an act of generosity, to pay off the debt, they would then fold the piece over as a sign that it had been paid. In fact, (I am told), the Hebrew actually talks about 'the double', in specific reference to this practice. This would make more sense, (for me, anyway), as instead of portraying God in a  harsh and vengeful light, exacting more than was the due penalty for the sin, it shows that He Himself has borne the cost of it. Like much of Isaiah, in fact, looking forward to the redemptive sacrifice of Christ.

Comment: Hi Helen Stengel, welcome! Thank you for your contribution. Personally it wasn't the easiest to read answer due to its format, but I also didn't know how to make it better

Comment: Hello Helen - are you able to provide any Bible (or other) references to support your assertions and argument?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing this important clarification  of the doubling over for sins. Many years ago, I had a wonderful friend and Bible scholar, the Reverend Bert Dearden, explained this very thing in a lecture. Dr. Dearden, a highly educated man, who was fluent in the Hebrew language and culture, explained that the proper translation was that she has received 'the doubling over' which indeed described the custom you have suggested. And as we know, Christ is the embodiment of this fact in his redemption of his people on Calvary. It it's indeed a beautiful truth!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/47412)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to understanding the words of the word, we also must account for figures of speech and orientalisms. Both are mostly misunderstood by the Western mind if they are even identified. In Isaiah 40, Bishop K.C. Pillai identifies and explains an orientalism of the Bible giving us a deeper, and proper understanding of God’s holy inerrant, matchless word.

**Double for Sin**

> > Isaiah 40:2 -- Speak ye comfortably to Jerusalem, and cry unto her, that her warfare is accomplished, that her iniquity is pardoned:  for she hath received of the Lord's hand double for all her sins.
>
> This verse seems to contradict itself. In the first half, Jerusalem's iniquity is pardoned, but the end of the verse says she has received of the Lord's hand double for all her sins. It sounds as though Jerusalem received twice the punishment, but this is not what the words really mean. The verse is referring to an oriental custom.
>
> In the East, the gates of the city had public bulletin boards, where various items could be posted by the citizens. If a man owed money, and couldn't repay it, his creditor would post the record at the city gate. Everyone would see what the man owed and it was a source of humiliation. Oftentimes a kinsman would pay the debt in full. When this happened the record was folded up, or the paper doubled over, so the debt was no longer displayed. He now had a clean slate.
> This is what God did for Jerusalem in Isaiah 40, and it is also what Christ did for us in:
>
> > Colossians 2: 13, 14 -- And you, being dead in your sins and the uncircumcision of your flesh, hath he quickened together with him, having forgiven you all trespasses; Blotting out the handwriting of ordinances that was against us, which was contrary to us, and took it out of the way, nailing it to his cross;
>
> Christ paid off the debt for our sins by 'blotting out the handwriting' (doubling over the paper), and nailing it to his cross. So, like the debtors of the East, we have a clean slate.”

Source: Orientalisms of the Bible Volume 1 - Bishop K.C. Pillai - Chapter 17, Double for Sin, pp.120- 125, ©️ 1969 by Mor-Mac Publishind Company, Inc. - ISBN #0-912178-02-7

Answer (score 0):

In Isaiah 40, the "double" seems to be a double punishment, probably a hyperbolic "double" to mean "complete" or "sufficient." Alternatively, it could refer to the penalty for stealing:

Exodus 22:4

> If the stolen animal is found alive in their possession—whether ox or
> donkey or sheep—they must pay back double.

However, it may also be a literary link to later in Isaiah where the "double" is used not to say "your debt is paid" but rather "I am now raising you to a position of favour."

Isaiah 61:7

> Instead of your shame you will receive a double portion, and instead
> of disgrace you will rejoice in your inheritance. And so you will
> inherit a double portion in your land, and everlasting joy will be
> yours.

Interestingly, Jeremiah combines the idea of paying a double punishment, with the idea of the inheritance:

> Jeremiah 16:18 "I will repay them double for their wickedness and
> their sin, because they have defiled my land with the lifeless forms
> of their vile images and have filled my inheritance with their
> detestable idols.”

Of course the double inheritance is a reference to Israel being God's firstborn:

Jer 31:9

> ... because I am Israel’s father, and Ephraim is my
> firstborn son.

Exodus 4:22

> Then say to Pharaoh, ‘This is what the Lord says: Israel
> is my firstborn son."

Deuteronomy 21:17

> He must acknowledge the son of his unloved wife as
> the firstborn by giving him a double share of all he has.

Jeremiah seems to be either using irony (because you have defiled your double portion you will be doubly punished) or maybe emphasising the responsibility that comes with the double portion. It is interesting that the roles of the first born were to (Sorry, I couldn't find any sources for this):

1. be a faithful representative of the father
2. care for the father's widows
3. care for the father's unmarried children

... and that both Jeremiah and Isaiah put a strong focus on how God's firstborn Israel:

1. bowed down to the idols that represented other Gods
2. oppressed widows
3. oppressed the fatherless
4. oppressed the foreigners living among them (perhaps see these as the fatherless of other nations)

Jeremiah 7:6-7

> If you do not oppress the foreigner, the fatherless or the widow and
> do not shed innocent blood in this place, and if you do not follow
> other gods to your own harm, then I will let you live in this place,
> in the land I gave your ancestors for ever and ever.

Isaiah 1:17

> Learn to do right! Seek justice, encourage the oppressed. Defend the
> cause of the fatherless, plead the case of the widow.

So even though Isaiah 41's double payment refers to a sufficient punishment, it is probably also emphasising the theme of Israel's responsibility for the vulnerable.